# pandas: identifying if a first character in an entry is a letter or number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to asking questions on here. But here it is:

I have a DataFrame that has a column called "id". I am looking to get rid of all rows that do not begin with a letter in that given column.
Below is an example of the DataFrame I am working with.

```
df=DataFrame({"level": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
 "personCode": [23,5,3,234,6567,232,67667,56,998,2456], 
"id":  ["Z71.89","J06.9","018.9","F41.1","M72.2","440.0","L85.1","000.00","000.00","I48.91"]})
```

I am working with a large dataset and I recently found out using for loops on a DataFrame of that size is just not feasible. I don't know any vectorized string method that would help me accomplish what I am doing. I'm basically looking for a boolean like isalpha() for the first character of each string in the "id" column. And once I find that, I want to delete the whole row.

I have been working on this for the past 2 days without any progress... Any feedback would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to check if the first character is not a letter:

```
df[~df.id.str[0].isalpha()]
#       id  level  personCode
#2   018.9      3           3
#5   440.0      6         232
#7  000.00      8          56
#8  000.00      9         998
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Literally this is exactly what I was looking for. I kept on using df[df.id.str[0].isalpha()]. What's the reason why there should be another '.str.'?

Comment: More out of habit than of necessity.

Answer (score 2):

One option is use `str.match`; here use regex *[^a-zA-Z]* to match a non alpha letter:

```
df[df.id.str.match('[^a-zA-Z]')]

#       id  level   personCode
#2   018.9      3   3
#5   440.0      6   232
#7  000.00      8   56
#8  000.00      9   998
```

---

Since `str.match` seems to be deprecated, you can use `str.contains` with an anchor `^` to specify the *beginning of a string*:

```
df[df.id.str.contains('^[^a-zA-Z]')]

#       id  level   personCode
# 2  018.9      3   3
# 5  440.0      6   232
# 7 000.00      8   56
# 8 000.00      9   998
```

---

Naive Timing of the `str.contains` method and `isalpha` with the sample data:

```
%timeit df[df.id.str.contains('^[^a-zA-Z]')]
#1000 loops, best of 3: 418 µs per loop

%timeit df[-df.id.str[0].str.isalpha()]
#1000 loops, best of 3: 576 µs per loop
```